# Decide Insert or Update on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wrote this function to save data to EF4 using POCOs classes:

```
public void Guardar(Pedidos myPedido)
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {
            if (myPedido.ID_Pedido == 0)
            {
                context.Pedidos.AddObject(myPedido);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Pedidos.Attach(myPedido);

                context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myPedido, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);                                        
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Now i want to write this in a generic way on a base class. Is there a way to decide if i need to do UPDATE or INSERT without using the ID? (ID_Pedido in this case), because the name on key field change on every object type. The rest of the code is generic. I'm traing to know if i need to use AddObject (new) or Attach(exist).
Thanks you!

Comment: I prefer to use the repository pattern; This will give you a better Separation of concern and SRP. Shall I write for you an example?

Comment: yes please! i'm new at this techlonogies.

Comment: It's all here: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/05/03/the-key-to-addorupdate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Found it myself! In case anyone face the same problem, here is the solution. I wrote this method:

```
public string getKey<T>() where T :new()
   {
       T _obj = new T();           
       return context.CreateEntityKey(_obj.ToString().Split('.')[2], _obj).EntityKeyValues[0].Key;
   }
```

Wich return the first Primary key of the object (in my case that's enough)

And use it like this:

```
string sKey = getKey<GruposComerciales>();
```

Now i can write a generic saveorupdate method on my repository. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

look to the method InsertOrUpdate! You can make this repository more generic; For example you can create an Entity base class and use it in a generic Approach.

```
public class Employee

{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

}




Now using this we will have a simple context class
public class HRContext : DbContext

{        

    public DbSet<DomainClasses.Employee> Employees { get; set; }

}


After that, define the repository interface IEmployeeRepository 


public interface IEmployeeRepository : IDisposable

{

    IQueryable<Employee> All { get; }

    IQueryable<Employee> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Employee, object>>[] includeProperties);

    Employee Find(int id);

    void InsertOrUpdate(Employee employee);

    void Delete(int id);

    void Save();

}

Then the Repository class called EmployeeRepository  

public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository

{

    HRContext context = new HRContext();


    public IQueryable<Employee> All

    {

        get { return context.Employees; }

    }


    public IQueryable<Employee> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Employee, object>>[] includeProperties)

    {

        IQueryable<Employee> query = context.Employees;

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties) {

            query = query.Include(includeProperty);

        }

        return query;

    }


    public Employee Find(int id)

    {

        return context.Employees.Find(id);

    }


    public void InsertOrUpdate(Employee employee)

    {

        if (employee.Id == default(int)) {

            // New entity

            context.Employees.Add(employee);

        } else {

            // Existing entity

            context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;

        }

    }


    public void Delete(int id)

    {

        var employee = context.Employees.Find(id);

        context.Employees.Remove(employee);

    }


    public void Save()

    {

        context.SaveChanges();

    }


    public void Dispose() 

    {

        context.Dispose();

    }

}
```

I get the soruce code from :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx

for example for a generic repository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class {

    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
    void Save();
}
```

Where T is the base entity for all your entities.
here is the complete generic example: 
http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle

Comment: A step up in some ways but _not_ more generic, which was the core question. Even with a `<T>`, you'd still need an `id` of a specific type.

Comment: What happens with a generic delete/add method when the entity has child entities?

Comment: This Job is not the delete method Job the responsisble for this is the Database you have to set the Setting in EF if the cascade deleting is enabled then the chlidrean or the realtions will be deleted. if you are using deattached entities you have to do that in the inherited repsoistory you are free how can you do it. Each entity should have an own repository for example TestEntity must have TestRepsoitory

Comment: Thank for that code. I'll give it a detail look and try to undestand. I see that in InsertOrUpdate you do " if (employee.Id == default(int)) {" wich agaien depends on object property son it can't be generic, but i try to adapt it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can query all parts of the primary key via Metadataworkspace

```
IDictionary<string, ICollection<EdmMember>> dict = // create instance ...    
MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
                             .First()
                             .BaseEntitySets
                             .ToList()
                             .ForEach(s => dict.Add(s.ElementType.Name, s.ElementType.KeyMembers));
```

With this I put the defined propertys of the primary key into a dictionary for later use.